# Not using JQuery-Mobile CSS possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After adding jquery mobile, every time I load my website, I am getting the following border around it and the following "loading..." header tag, shown in the picture below.

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to avoid it? It never disappears, even after I would expect it to complete loading.

Some of the css from the elements shown in the picture below, that gets dynamically added:

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span>
   <h1>loading</h1>
</div>
```

http://i46.tinypic.com/2rrp3yp.png

UPDATE: Just found that adding the jquery mobile css, fixed the problem, listed above, however, I am only using jquery mobile for one swipe event. Is there a way to not use jquery mobile's css?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a framework, are you using the html structure that it requires to work properly, along with the css?

Comment: I am just using the swipe event from JQM, upon detecting it is a touch enabled device, which seems to work perfectly, other than the problem specified above.

Comment: Do I honestly have to restructure the whole web site to comply with jquery mobile requirements, in order to use one of its events, on one of the elements only?

Comment: This problem is fixed when I add the jquery-mobile css, but doing so messes up the whole styling of my website, is there any workaround?

Comment: If you just need the swipe event, you should not use a whole framework.

Comment: what other options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building a version of jQuery Mobile that just has Touch.

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

- Note: This download builder is beta software currently so use at your own risk.